# Why doesn't this code work? I tested all the different parts separately and they all work

Tags: c#

This code is a kind of "anagram finder" it use simple .txt files as "database"(for example all_a4.txt contains all the words starting by "a" AND that are 4 characters long). It takes an input from the user and compare it to a list of words created with those txt files. it than  compares the alphabetically sorted version of the user input with the alphabetically sorted version of every word with the same length as the user input. If they are the same it adds the matched word in a list that is displayed later on.

The problem that I have is that it just simply doesn't work... I tried many things and I'm stuck on this for 2 days now, and I can't find what did I do wrong? I just very recently started to learn programming, so a little help would be much appreciated, internet doesn't seem to have an answer.

So I already tried making arrays instead of lists, I added `Console.WriteLine(alphabeticaly sorted input);`
`Console.WriteLine(alphabeticaly sorted dictonary word);`
to my foreach loop to check if my different functions were working properly, if they sort words well, etc. I purposely input some word that I knew would match and yet... every time it tells me the anagramlist is empty.

I also downloaded LINQpad5 to be able to use an interpreter to check every small group of related expressions or functions and everything works fine separately.

THE CODE.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace find_mot{

    class Program{
        static string userWord;

        static void Main(string[] args){
            
            string userw = inputWord();
            List<string> liste_finale = Listing() ;
            List<string> anAgList = new List<string>();
            bool plein = anAgList.Any<string>();

            foreach (string word in liste_finale){ /* we apply "Tri()" on both userinput and the whole list of corresponding words
                                                       to see if some of them match */
                string u = Tri(userw);
                string u2 = Tri(word);
                
                if (u == u2){ /* if it match = anagram found ! then add this (word) to anAgList */
                    Console.WriteLine("found");
                    anAgList.Add(word);
                }
            }
            if (plein is false) /* if no anagram were found, we tell the user */
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No anagrams found for {0}", userw);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {

                foreach (string ana in anAgList) /* we print the anagrams from newly created anAgList */
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ana);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static List<string> Listing (){

            /* Creates a list of all the words with the same length as the user 
             * input, the list is created from txt files that i've got in a 
             * specific path,
             * after testing this function works as intended */

            List<string> liste_fin = new List<string>();
            int len = userWord.Length;
            string lenS = len.ToString();
            string[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
                                   "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i+=1){
                string path = "C:/Users/asus/Desktop/prog python/charm/all_" + alphabet[i] + lenS;
                string[] allLetters = File.ReadAllLines( path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")); /* Latin-1 cuz this is a french dictionary */
                liste_fin.AddRange(allLetters);
            }
            return liste_fin;
        }

        public static string inputWord(){

            /* input taken from user , works fine */

            Console.WriteLine("Entrez un mot dont vous voulez tous les anagrammes:");
            userWord = Console.ReadLine();
            return userWord;
        }

        public static string Tri(string args ){

            /* this function takes a word and return an alphabeticaly sorted version of it, this works fine too when tested */

            char[] array1 = args.ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(array1);
            string sortedWord = new string(array1);
            return sortedWord;

        }
    }
}
```

For example if I input "rai" which is 3 characters long I expect it to print the ONLY corresponding French anagram "air" (same meaning as English for the record, so you can get it) by the way I made sure that "air" was in my text files off course.

EDIT: SOLVED! everything was syntactically fine, the txt files were just formatted in a weird way somehow, figured it out thanks to debugging! thank you all

Comment: Debug your code, you will see step by step what does your code actually do and realize what causes the missbehavior

Comment: This check is wrong `if (plain is false)`. The `is` checks for type not for value. For example, `object myObject = new Person("Sam")`. This `if  (myObject is Person)` woul return true, but to check the value of the name property you should use the equality comparator `==`. `if (myObject.Name == "Sam")`

Comment: debugging says it has 0 mistakes. And thx bradbury9 for the explanation , I got it with the boolean value , unfortunately the issue seems elsewhere but still can't figure it out :(

Comment: You did compile, and compiling raised no errors. Setting breakpoints at executing the code step by step allows you to see the flow of the code, check what the variables contain, detect at what point you expected the code do something it didn't do. Learning to debug will save you tons of time

Comment: ohh alright bradbury, thanks  a lot ; just read a bit about it and i was unaware of that . My experience with programming before starting c# 5 days ago was just one intensive month of python. Have to say I love c# but its more strict :(

Comment: I love c# **because** it is more strict

Comment: `debugging says it has 0 mistakes` Debugging is an interactive process - not a report.   **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating the value of `plein` before you add anything to `anAgList` and the value is not updated after words are added to `anAgList`.
Try calculating the value after the foreach loop.
Also the usage of operator `is` is incorrect, since it is used for type checking (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is).
Try using `==` there, or even better use only the boolean variable for the condition.

Comment: Thx a lot, but unfortunately there is somthg else

Answer (score 0):

So I tried something different to try resolve this...I got rid of the boolean to simplify the problem. Instead of the boolean I use the variable int i to count whenever a word match and if the counter is still = to 0 when the whole list of word is fully iterated, i tell the user there is no anagram. But it's exactly the same result...doesn't seem to work in any way : (

The code is now this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace find_mot{

    class Program{
        static string userWord;

        static void Main(string[] args){

            string userw = inputWord();
            List<string> liste_finale = Listing() ;
            List<string> anAgList = new List<string>();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string word in liste_finale){ /* we apply "Tri()" on both userinput and the whole list of corresponding words
                                                       to see if some of them match */
                string u = Tri(userw);
                string u2 = Tri(word);


                if (u == u2){ /* if it match = anagram found ! then add this (word) to anAgList */

                    Console.WriteLine("found");
                    anAgList.Add(word);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
            if (i == 0) /* if no anagram were found , we tell the user */
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No anagrams found for {0}", userw);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( i + " anagrams were found for " + userw);
                foreach (string ana in anAgList) /* we print the anagrams from newly created anAgList */
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ana);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static List<string> Listing (){

            /* Creates a list of all the words with the same length as the user 
             * input, the list is created from txt files that i've got in a 
             * specific path,
             * after testing this function works as intended */

            List<string> liste_fin = new List<string>();
            int len = userWord.Length;
            string lenS = len.ToString();
            string[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
                                   "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i+=1){
                string path = "C:/Users/asus/Desktop/prog python/charm/all_" + alphabet[i] + lenS;
                string[] allLetters = File.ReadAllLines( path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")); /* Latin-1 cuz this is a french dictionary */
                liste_fin.AddRange(allLetters);
            }
            return liste_fin;
        }

        public static string inputWord(){

            /* input taken from user , works fine */

            Console.WriteLine("Entrez un mot dont vous voulez tous les anagrammes:");
            userWord = Console.ReadLine();
            return userWord;
        }

        public static string Tri(string args ){

            /* this function takes a word and return an alphabeticaly sorted version of it, this works fine too when tested */

            char[] array1 = args.ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(array1);
            string sortedWord = new string(array1);
            return sortedWord;

        }
    }
}
```

Also, ty everybody for these answers it helped me to learn but the problem is elsewhere :(

Comment: btw, I upvoted all your answers but as im a new contributor these seems to not being displayed :(